Using Multiple Objects in Workshop Application
Table Relationships
I am in the process of building a Palantir Workshop application but have run into some issues around the objects needed for the app. I have seven datasets created by a python transform and the image shows the seven tables and how they are related.
The application will require these tables to remain separate so that they can be maintained for additions, deletions, etc. I am not looking for the answer to how to do all of this but the question is really geared towards methodology. The main application will be a display of filtered results from the tables but only using a small subset of the columns from each table.

After creating the objects in the Ontology Manager, should links between the objects be created and are they needed at that stage?
Since filters will be needed, would it be better to create object sets and filters?


The general methodology is to create Object Types that represents the business concepts you are working with.
e.g. In your case, maybe "Course" and "Statistics" ? Really unsure.
To do this, you can:

Create the backing datasets that represents those Objects Types
Create the Objects Types in Ontology Manager
Create Links between those Object Types in Ontology Manager - this will allow you to move from one set of Objects to another set of object without specifying filter conditions (e.g. you can just say "get me the owners of those cars" and you will get the set of "Owners" that belongs to the set of "cars")
In Workshop, you create variables that contains "all" the object instance of a given Object Type (e.g. a variable that contains "all cars")
In Workshop, you can then use those variables to populate widgets, which will generate new variables which you can use further down the line (e.g. you use a table, provide a "all cars" variable  and then get a "selected cars" variable, which you can use further in other Widgets, same with filters widgets, ...)
In Workshop, you can derive new variables from existing variables, for example move from the "selected cars" to the "related owners", and then use those variables as any other variables. No need to know how they relate !

So in short, for your question: It depends on your data model. If relations between your Objects make sense, I would encourage you to create a relation in Ontology Manager, so that you can easily search around from one Object Type to another.
